# Call do_fork inside kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, fork

For some experimental purposes i need to create a child kernel process without shared memory. As i know, the kthread_create and kernel_thread routines is always call do_fork with CLONE_VM. But i need to call do_fork without CLONE_VM

I have found in arch/x86_64/kernel/process.c(x86_64 is a suitable architecture for the experiment):

```
asmlinkage long sys_fork(struct pt_regs *regs)
{
        return do_fork(SIGCHLD, regs->rsp, regs, 0, NULL, NULL);
}
```

I think, i should call do_fork(SIGCHLD, regs->rsp, regs, 0, NULL, NULL). But i can't understand how to setup the pt_regs structure. I want to setup the structure based on registers of the current process.
Is there is a function to fill pt_regs based on current process? Or maybe there is an different way how to create process with own memory inside kernel?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel's address space is **always** shared between processes. `CLONE_VM` flag affects only on user address space sharing.

So, if you need kernel process, just use `kthread_create`. Thread, created with this functions, is allowed to use only kernel address space.

Answer (score 0):

You need not fill out the *pt_regs* structure; the only thing used from it is the stack pointer of the user-space task.  Routine names of the form *sys_foo* are always expecting user-space values; for example, any address value passed in MUST be a user-space address.  On the other hand, worker routines formed like *do_foo* expect kernel-space values; never call *sys_foo* from inside the kernel.